# Autocommand for i_CTRL-x mode?

Tags: autocmd, ins-completion

Is there a way to run a function when entering `i_CTRL-X` (ins-completion) mode? It doesn't seem to be an event I can run an autocmd for?

I can just imap `C-S-x` (say) to run my function and then call `C-x`. And there is `CompleteDone` event for leaving.
But it would be nicer if there was an event for entering this mode as well.

Context:
I want to use ins-completion to complete text involving braces and other brackets. Adding these things to `iskeyword` breaks many text objects and pattern matching. So I would like to modify `iskeyword` when entering and leaving this mode.

I work with small enough files that I don't need to worry about the lag when vim re-processes the file.

Comment: Did you consider perusing `:help autocommand-events`?

Comment: Couldn't spot one there. I'm a bit of a noob so I may have missed it.